# A template static map of template objects with different parameter lists

Tags: c++, templates

I'm asking about creating a template map of objects of different types, 
Observer example is just a convenient way to describe the problem.

So, I have a simple implementation of the Observer pattern:

```cpp
template<typename ...A> class Observable
{
    typedef void(*EventListener)(A...);  /* Listener callback type */
public:
    void addListener(EventListener listener);
    void removeListener(EventListener listener);
    void fireEvent(A... args);
};
```

There are different sets of events with different listener signatures in my code each represented by enum, i.e.:

```cpp
enum PCEvents {
  JUMPED = 0,       // void (*fn)(int, int)
  WALKED = 1,       // void (*fn)(int)
  DIED = 2,         // void (*fn)()
  DIED_HORRIBLY = 3 // void (*fn)(const std::string&)
};
```

Now i want an umbrella class that encapsulates all Observables based on the enum. 
I don't know how it can be implemented, so here is its desired instantiation:

```cpp
void gameOver(const std::string& deathCause)
{
    std::cout << "You perished because of " << deathCause << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // parameter list syntax is lax 
    PoorGuyObserver<PCEvents, void (*)(int, int), void (*)(int), void (*)(), void (*)(const std::string&)> observer;

    observer.addListener(PCEvents::DIED_HORRIBLY, gameOver);
    observer.fireEvent(PCEvents::DIED_HORRIBLY, "gazeebo");
}
```

I'm intrested in a solution for c++14.

Comment: To begin with I recommend that you shouldn't use pointers to non-member functions, as those aren't very flexible (you can't use member functions or lambdas or other callable objects). Instead use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: And perhaps you shouldn't try to invent a signal/slot system yourself, and use something which already exists. If you already use Qt then use their systems, or if you use Boost then perhaps its [Signals 2 library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not for production and not about Observable per se. I'm intrested if it is possible to implement this kind of map with current templates.

Comment: You should avoid using pointers to functions in OOP on any language. Use interfaces instead.

Comment: I think what they're asking is _how can you templetize the observable in the observer pattern_ so that it can be generated for any observer. Here is an example on github: https://github.com/ddinu/observable . That's for a single event, it seems they're asking for something similar that covers multiple events tagged by an enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of your problem was that you wanted to describe an observable as a map of enum values to function signatures, and use a variadic template to generate it.

One tricky bit with variadic templates is that you can't mix constant values with type names. The trailing bit has to either be all type names (`typename...`) or all constants (`auto...`). So the first step for me was to make a helper type:

```cpp
template <typename TEnum, TEnum Id, typename... TArgs>
struct Event;
```

*Note: If you were using c++17, you could combine to first two arguments as `auto Id`, but you specified C++14*

Next step: implement the observable for a single `Event`. Normally, this would be part of the recursive variadic template, but this was needed for a tricky problem I'll describe later.

```cpp
template <typename TEnum, TEnum Id, typename... TArgs>
struct ObservableImpl {
    std::vector<std::function<void(TArgs...)>> subscribers;

    template <TEnum FireId, typename = std::enable_if_t<FireId == Id>>
    void fire(TArgs... args) { 
        for (auto subscriber : subscribers) { 
            subscriber(args...); 
        }
    }

    template <TEnum SubscribeId, typename = std::enable_if_t<SubscribeId == Id>>
    void subscribe(std::function<void (TArgs...)> handler) {
        subscribers.push_back(handler);
    }
};
```

Then, the recursive part. Each inheritance layer inherits from the single-event implementation, and promotes `fire` and `subscribe`.

```cpp
template <typename... TEvents>
struct Observable;

// Recursive case, implement the current event, inherit from the next
template <typename TEnum, TEnum Id, typename... TArgs, typename... TEvents>
struct Observable<Event<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>, TEvents...> : public ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>, Observable<TEvents...> {
    using Observable<TEvents...>::subscribe;
    using Observable<TEvents...>::fire;
    using ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>::subscribe;
    using ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>::fire;
};

// Terminal case, implement the last event
template <typename TEnum, TEnum Id, typename... TArgs>
struct Observable<Event<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>> : public ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...> {
    using ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>::subscribe;
    using ObservableImpl<TEnum, Id, TArgs...>::fire;
};
```

In many examples, the terminating specialization is empty. But in our case, because the recursive specialization promotes a base method, the terminating case has to have that base method. That's why I pulled the single-event implementation out to a second class, to save some typing.

After that, it's ready to use:

```cpp
enum class Events { 
  JUMPED = 0,       // void (*fn)(int, int)
  WALKED = 1,       // void (*fn)(int)
  DIED = 2,         // void (*fn)()
  DIED_HORRIBLY = 3 // void (*fn)(const std::string&)
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Observable<
        Event<Events, Events::JUMPED, int, int>,
        Event<Events, Events::WALKED, int>,
        Event<Events, Events::DIED>,
        Event<Events, Events::DIED_HORRIBLY, std::string>> observable;

    observable.subscribe<Events::JUMPED>([](int x, int y) { std::cout << "jumped(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n"; });
    observable.subscribe<Events::WALKED>([](int distance) { std::cout << "walked(" << distance << ")\n"; });
    observable.subscribe<Events::DIED>([]() { std::cout << "died()\n"; });
    observable.subscribe<Events::DIED_HORRIBLY>([](std::string how) { std::cout << "died_horribly(" << how << ")\n"; });

    observable.fire<Events::JUMPED>(1, 2);
    observable.fire<Events::WALKED>(42);
    observable.fire<Events::DIED>();
    observable.fire<Events::DIED_HORRIBLY>("fire");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/VhvGPg